# How make theme css be first and not plugin css

Tags: css

I have in theme `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />`
I had 3.6 wordpress with my own theme and plugins witch have css. Since on update changes in plugin css i made changed on plugin update then i put just what i change in theme css. Now i did wordpress 3.7.1 update and somehow now plugin css is overtaking my theme css changes.

PS maybe helps. Also Previously admin menu on beeing logged in was just showing 25px space. Now this top admin menu shows up in my theme when im logged in.

Comment: to disable admin bar you can use the answer below, while for css, if you don't want to remove it, use !important in your theme css for overriding plugin css

Answer (score 1):

The best way to override plugin css is with specificity. That way you only need to target the rules which you want to override.

You should also verify that `wp_head();` is just before the closing  tag and not before your `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />`

If you really need to get rid of the plugin's css you can use `wp_dequeue_script();` and then you would have to write your own css for the plugin.

The admin bar is supposed to show up by default unless it has specifically been overridden. To disable the admin bar for all users except admin:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
 if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
show_admin_bar(false);
 }
}
```

Or for all users:

```
 show_admin_bar(false);
```

Your plugin might also have incompatibility issues with 3.7. It might be worth contacting them or looking it up.